# При уменьшении TextInputLayout не вижу вводимого текста

Tags: android, xml

Я хочу все EditText поменять на  TextInputLayout что бы можно было сделать скрытие пароля, но при уменьшении размера не видно что пишит юзер.Помогите исправить.
android:hardwareAccelerated="false" в манифесте нету уже проверил.Помогите пожалуйста.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        tools:context=".RegistrationActivity">
    
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/reg_txt"
            android:layout_width="225dp"
            android:layout_height="29dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Добро пожаловать!"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:translationY="130dp" />
    
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="357dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/registration_block"
            android:translationY="190dp" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/login_txt"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="29dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Регистрация"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:translationY="230dp" />
    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_name_input"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:translationY="280dp"
            android:background="@drawable/input"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:hint="Имя"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColorHint="#9D99AC"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            />
    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_phone_input"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:translationY="330dp"
            android:background="@drawable/input"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:hint="Номер телефона"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColorHint="#9D99AC"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            />
    
    
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            app:passwordToggleTint="@color/white">
    
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:hint="Пароль"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
    
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    
    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_password_input"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/input"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_icon_pass"
            android:hint=" Пароль"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="#9D99AC"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:translationY="380dp"
            />
    
    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_password_two_input"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/input"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_icon_pass"
            android:hint="Пароль"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="#9D99AC"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:translationY="430dp"
    
    
            />
    
    
    
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image_reg_Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_login"
            android:translationY="480dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: TextInputLayout не может быть такого же размера как и TextInputEditText в нем, так как требует места еще и под label

Answer (score 0):

Не надо устанавливать фиксированную высоту для полей ввода. Сделайте её `wrap_content`. И для `TextInputEditText` и для `TextInputLayout`